# Rest application and authorization

Tags: rest, oauth, authorization

I would like to build my own REST app.

I'm planning to use oAuth as a main auth approach.

The question is: Can I use login and password as client_id and client_secret (in terms oAuth spec) ?

I don't have any third side applications, companies, sites etc... which will authenteficate my users.

I have my own REST server and JS-application.

Whole site will be made in usual(RPC) approach, but some private part will be done as RESTfull service, with enough stand-alone JS application.

UPDATED: I'm not sure that I even need full oAuth support. It seems to me that I can ask login and password on https page and then generate some token. Later i could use it to check is this user authenticated already or not. But in this case this oAuth become almost the same what we have in web aplications. I do not need oAuth to athorize users ?

I'm not consider HTTP(s) authotization because i don't want to send evrytime user and password to server.

Comment: Do you mean oauth_consumer_key and oauth_consumer_secret?

Comment: I guess yes exactly these one

Answer (score 0):

No.

One if the main reasons OAuth exists is to allow integrations without users compromising their usernames and passwords.

If you plan on using username and password, look into xAuth as an option if you still want to sign your requests. More info: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth.

But you could likely just as well go for HTTP Basic Authentication. At least if you publish your API over SSL. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Usually oAuth used to authorized third party software to interact with RESTfull server. But in my case i don't have such. I have only JS (stand-alone) application (i would say JS Ajax application without any other pages, everything will be loaded by Ajax). I don't want to send everytime credentials, with oAuth i could use only token, but in my case it seems like session_id

Comment: Well, in that case you can use cookie authentication. Provided that your js-client and the server code is on the same domain. But that's just normal in-house web development you're describing...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get a better answer on the [security site](https://security.stackexchange.com/).  See, for example, [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7307/3304).

In any case, you need to start with a detailed assessment of what attacks you are trying to prevent and what attacks are "acceptable.". For example, if you are using HTTPS then you can probably accept the remaining danger of a man-in-the-middle attack, because it would require forging an SSL certificate. It is harder to say in general if a replay attack is acceptable.

One reasonable solution would be to create a time-limited temporary token by having the user authenticate over HTTPS with the username and password, generating a secure token with an expiration date, and then sending that token and expiration date back to the client. For example, you can create a (reasonably) secure token by taking the SHA1 hash of a secret plus the user name plus the expiration timestamp.  Then the client can include the token, the user name, and the authentication timestamp in future requests and you can validate it using your secret and your clock.  These need not be sent as 3 parameters; they can be concatenated into one string `user|timestamp|token`.

Comment: thanks, i will check links what you gave, could you tell me in access_token case what should I do when it is expired but user still is working in system ? should I regenerate it in transparent mode ?

Comment: @user, it's up to you if you want to generate a new token or require the user to re-authenticate. The first is more convenient, the second is more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Register your application with SLI. SLI grants a unique client ID and a client secret that enables your application to authenticate to the SLI API. You must also register the redirect URI of your application for use in authentication and authorization flows.

Enable your application with specific education organizations so that the application can be approved for use in those districts.

Configure and implement the appropriate OAuth 2.0 authentication and authorization flow in your application, which includes managing sessions and authorization timeouts.